# drag and drop causes button to disappear

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, visibility

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop with some buttons. My OnTouchListener for each button looks as follows

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder dsb = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(clipData, dsb, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

which so far is working fine, but my OnDragListener is having an issue. When dragging buttons to switch across layouts I don't have a problem, but when clicking the button in place, it sometimes (NOT ALWAYS) turns invisible. I suspect it's the ACTION_DRAG_ENDED but have no idea. Here is my code for the OnDragListener

```
private final class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    private boolean containsDragable = true;

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {

        int dragAction = dragEvent.getAction();
        View dragView = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();
        if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED) {
            containsDragable = false;
        } else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED) {
            containsDragable = true;
        } else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED) {
            if (!dragEvent.getResult()) {
                dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (dragAction == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP && containsDragable) {
            rearrangeButtons((LinearLayout) view, dragView);
            dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }

private void rearrangeButtons(LinearLayout view, View dragView) {
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) dragView.getParent();
        owner.removeView(dragView);
        view.addView(dragView);

        View v = view.getChildAt(0);
        Button button = (Button) v;
        view.removeView(v);
        owner.addView(v);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Each button is enclosed in its own LinearLayout, not sure if that is a cause.

Thanks to anybody who can help!

Comment: @user3956566 i need to be able to switch my buttons' positions and didn't know how to have listeners recognize positions within a single LinearLayout. Do you think that's why I'm having this disappearing bug?